# C++ Vector unable to push_back

Tags: c++, vector

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing this error:

[image: CMD Line error capture]

Source below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class taco {
private:
    //Classes
    class ingredient {
        private:
            //Ingredients have basic flavors
            //Flavors should total 100% for ingredients
            float sweet;
            float sour;
            float bitter;
            float salt;
            float umami; //Difficult taste to define, generally synonomous with savory or meaty
            //Ingredients have flavor modifiers
            bool hot; //Is the ingredient served Hot or Cold?
            short intensity; //How bland is the ingredient (100% for flavorful, 0% for flavorless)
            short moist; //100% for liquid (sauces etc) higher % to represent juice meats or fruits
        public:
            ingredient ( float sweet = 30.0, float sour = 0.0, float bitter = 0.0, float salt = 60.0, float umami = 10.0, bool hot = false, float intensity = 30.0, float moist = 25.0) {
                //Default ingredient is flour tortilla
                this->sweet = sweet; //Grains typically have a sugary tast even though it might not be very strong
                this->sour = sour;
                this->bitter = bitter;
                this->salt = salt; //Tortillas do have a salt content as well, it might not be very strong but this 60% represents a total out of the 100% flavor, the strength is determined by intensity
                this->umami = umami; //Most foods have at least small amounts of umami. Its umami that gives two foods with similliar tastes, different flavors. 
                this->hot = hot; //While a steamed tortilla is good, tortillas can be served either steamed or unsteamed. We default to not steamed as steamed tortilla will be a different ingredient
                this->intensity = intensity; //Tortillas are relatively bland. They have a destinctive taste and can affect the overall taste of a taco but the taste is not very intense
                this->moist = moist; //Flour tortillas are not generally moist but if there was no water content they would be brittle and unbending. Steamed tortillas and corn tortillas are usually more moist.
            }
    };

    //Vectors
    vector<ingredient> ingredients; //Create vector to store ingredients

public:
taco () {
    ingredient defIngredient();
    this->ingredients.push_back(defIngredient);
}

void foo ( ingredient bar ) {
    this->ingredients.push_back(bar);
}

};

int main ( void ) { 
return 0;
}
```

My experience with vectors is basically nothing but I can't figure out why it is saying that it cannot convert the type. The vector is defined as type ingredient and the value I'm attempting to push to it is of the same type.

EDIT: 
I apologize, this isn't the error I meant to post, I've updated it a smidge. The previous code was after playing around with things. I do realize that there was a difference in type int hat code.

Comment: Give us a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org) and we'll take a look.

Comment: `ingredient defIngredient();` declares a function.  Get rid of the `()` and read about vexing parse..

Comment: Bagh I was trying to use the default constructor, Thanks, works now.

Comment: Without the parentheses you are still using the default constructor, you just can't use them if you aren't passing arguments because that parses as a function declaration.

Comment: Right, I was focusing on vectors cause I never used em I forgot to check my syntax on using classes 8-P I'm reviewing the syntax now. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common error:

```
ingredient defIngredient();
```

is *not* initializing with the empty constructor.

Use

```
ingredient defIngredient;
```

instead. It is The-One-Exception that is very nasty and easily overlooked.

To not fall into that trap again use C++11 and **always initialize with the new `{...}`-syntax**.

```
ingredient defIngredient{};
```

---

Anyway. Consider using **initializers** in your constructor:

```
class ingredient {
    private:
...
        ingredient()
          : sweet(30.0), sour(0.0), bitter(0.0), salt(60.0), umami(10.0),
            hot(false), intensity(30.0), moist(25.0)
          {}
```

Or with C++11 **member initializators**

```
class ingredient {
    private:
        float sweet = 30.0f;
        float sour = 0.0f;
        float bitter = 0.0f;
        float salt = 60.0f;
        float umami = 10.0f;
        bool hot = false;
        short intensity = 30;
        short moist = 25;
 }; // no default c'tor needed anymore
```

Speaking of C++11:

The better old C++ is:

```
void foo ( const ingredient& bar ) {
    this->ingredients.push_back(bar);
}
```

which may save you one copy of the object.

In C++11 you van use value-semantics (which is always a good thing) for the parameter and still save the copy -- but with the const-ref above you are already 90% the way.

```
void foo ( ingredient bar ) {
    this->ingredients.emplace_back(std::move(bar));
}
```

Maybe that gives you a boost towards C++.

Answer (score 3):

`ingredients` is a `vector<ingredient*>` - as you can see, it contains **pointers to `ingredient`**.  You are trying to push back `bar`, which is **an `ingredient`** itself.

You can't just do `&bar` instead (well it would compile, but it won't work), because `bar` is a local object and will be destroyed very soon.

Instead, you should just store `ingredient` objects in your vector:

```
vector<ingredient> ingredients;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have vector of pointers, and what you try to push_back is not a pointer to ingredient but ingredient object. Start from changing `vector<ingredient*> ingredients;` to `vector<ingredient> ingredients;`.

Answer (score 2):

The vector actually has the wrong type. You define your vector as `vector<ingredient*>` (a vector containing pointers to ingredient) but instead of pushing a pointer you are pushing by value.

You can fix your code by either changing the vector to a `vector<ingredient>` (omiting the asterisk) or making the function foo take a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your vector contains pointers :-

```
vector<ingredient*> ingredients; //Create vector to store ingredients
```

But you are trying to push an object :-

```
void foo ( ingredient bar ) {
    this->ingredients.push_back(bar);
```

You maybe wanted vector to store actual object, not pointers to them?

Answer (score 1):

when using user define type as element of vector , default constructor & copy constructor should be provided.

when using push_back, the first step is create a object using default constructor ,the second step is copy the currect element to the new object in the vecotor, which is unefficient，vector is a better way

when you create an object using operator new, you won't have to worry about the local variable

```
taco () {
    ingredient *defIngredient = new ingredient();
    this->ingredients.push_back(defIngredient);
}
```

remember to delete the objects in the destructor functions

```
~ingredient （）
{
   for(vector<ingredient*>::iterator vec_iter = ingradients.begin();
                                     vec_iter != ingradients.end(); ++ vec_iter)
   {
        if(*vec_iter)
        {
            delete *vec_iter;
            *vec_iter = NULL;
        }
   }
}
```

notes: when the object the frequently copyed and used in other class, shared_ptr can be applied.

Comment: when using push_back, the first step is create a object using default constructor ,the second step is copy the currect element to the new object in the vecotor, which is unefficient，vector<ingredient*> is a better way

Comment: I've been thinking about your comment for a while. To me, even though it seems more efficient, it seems like the object creation would need to happen within the main function so that the objects can persist (if we create an object in a method within the taco class, the object would get destroyed when it's out of scope making the pointer worthless). Above, we create an object, put it in the vector and than allow the object to be destroyed at the end of scope while keeping a persistent copy in the vector. If you can show me a better way to do this I'd love to see it but I can't see it in my head

Comment: @Toby when you create an object using operator new, you won't have to worry about the local variable, I have add the way I would usually apply in the answer , hope it will help